# How to test redux actions that use 'redux-api-middleware' and [CALL_API]?

Tags: testing, reactjs, redux, middleware, react-redux

I have an action called `addItemsToCollection` which triggers a call to an API like so:

```
import {CALL_API} from 'redux-api-middleware';

export function addItemsToCollection(collectionId, itemIds)
{
  return {[CALL_API]:
  {
      endpoint: `/collections/${collectionId}/items`,
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(itemIds),
      types:
      [
        ADD_ITEMS,
        { type: ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS },
        ADD_ITEMS_FAIL
      ]
    }
  };
}
```

When I try to write a test simply for this action being created such as:

```
it('should create an action to add items to a collection', () =>
{
  const collectionId = 1;
  const itemIds = [1,2,3];

  const expectedAction =
  {
    [CALL_API]:
    {
      endpoint: `/collections/${collectionId}/items`,
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(itemIds),
      types:
      [
        ADD_ITEMS,
        { type: ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS },
        ADD_ITEMS_FAIL
      ]
    }
  };

  expect(addItemsToCollection(collectionId, itemIds)).toEqual(expectedAction);
});
```

It does pass but that is because it is returning and empty object {} for expectedAction as well as from the action creator function. Not much use.

So my questions are,

**Why are empty objects being returned?**

**What is the proper way to make this test?**

Answer (score 1):

CALL_API is a Symbol. They do not show up when just passing the object to console.log. If you want to see the key in your object you can do `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(expectedAction)` or you can `console.log(expectedAction[CALL_API])` and you will get that object. (http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_symbols.html)

You are testing it correctly.  If you were to use an empty object, it would not match. If you use an object that has a different Symbol, it will not match.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this problem, you need to add { apiMiddleware } from redux-api-middleware to your mock store.

Comment: Could you provide a bit of code as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected data should not be calculated because it's a part of what you are testing :

```
const expectedAction =
{
  [CALL_API]: {
    endpoint: '/collections/1/items',
    method: 'POST',
    body: "[1,2,3]",
    types:
    [
      ADD_ITEMS,
      { type: ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS },
      ADD_ITEMS_FAIL
    ]
  }
};
```

You can eventually mock the constants and use raw data.

For your empty objects, it might depend on your import, mocks, testing tools... There are too many options.